# Symfony3 form with variables from records of a database table

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I would like to create a form with Symfony.

The fields listed in the form are retrieved from a database table. So the form can be smoothly modified.

Do you have any idea on of how it can be implemented? With the Form Component? With another tool?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. During building the form, you can pass existed entity object to fill the form with it's data.

In "Building the Form" section we pass new Task() object in line 16. If you pass object with filled data - you'll get form with filled fields and it will modify your data in DB after submit.

Please, see https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/forms.html for more details